# I want to create multiple button on single image in Android Application

Tags: android, imagebutton, imagemap

For Example:

Consider *Circular Image* into 4 segments

> Button1 - Top part of image()
>
> Button2 - Bottom part of image()
>
> Button3 - Left part of image()
>
> Button4 - Right part of image()

Please give feedback ASAP.

I have read the following post but didn't get clear idea.

[Making one image into several image buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113678/making-one-image-into-several-image-buttons)

Answer (score 2):

Define different parts of your image as clickable parts.
 
Have a look at this post http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/